# 22.10 Won't boot after upgrading

Tags: boot, 22.10

The upgrade seemed to go fine then after I shut it down it will not boot. Here are the errors:

Dev loop1: unable to read RDB block 8
Dev loop5: unable to read RDB block 8

I attached a pic of some errors as well. Sorry it's not clear.
[image: errors]

Comment: The monitor appears to be showing two streams of input simultaneously, making things a bit difficult to read, but the `Finished GRUB failed boot detection` item stands out as something that could be resolved first. Grab your Ubuntu installation USB stick and boot into a Live Session. From there, open Terminal and try to repair GRUB with `sudo grub-install /dev/sdX`. Be sure to replace `sdX` with the actual boot device, which may be prefixed with `sd` or `nvm`.

Comment: Thanks! I did that and got the error grub-install: error: failed to get canonical path of '/cow'. Any thoughts?